# How i can export Android code to java library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, gradle

I'm developing a library for an Android application, I wrote some classes that contains different functions.

I have a problem in the exporting process from Java to Jar. I did the following:

1) From an existing source code, File -> New module -> Java Library

2) Android Studio at this point create a "sub project", with a default class

3) Cut and paste my java code in the library created at point 2

At this point I have some problems/questions:

- Some part of code cannot be resolved like ByteBuffer, JSON...
- Should I import in the JSON - HTTP library?
- I don't understand why ConnectivityManager, NetworkInfo cannot be resolved.

**EDIT 1**

[image: Step 1 - App Project]

[image: New module -> Java Library]

app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MY ID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
}
```

Di gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are moving the code in another subproject and then building it differently. To fix this, assuming you are using Android Studio, move into your module Gradle.build file all the library you need in the new module.

Comment: Sorry I don't undestand. I use Android Studio, as first step i have created new Android Project, I created my classed and tested it exporting the project as apk. Now i what use classes to build a jar. Supposing that point 1, 2 are correct, what is the next step ?

Comment: You have created another module on your project with the Android Studio wizard, have you? If so, you should see a Gradle.build file with the module name into the project view. Can you post the content of all your Gradle files? Thank you.

Comment: Move this line into your Di gradle: compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar') and synchronize. It should import everything correctly then. Keep in mind that when you are working with modules, each one will have its own imports and then Gradle will filter the conflicting one while builds the whole app.

Comment: The source code of my classes must be moved to "di" ?? Could you confirm to me that this procedure create a .jar ?

Comment: If you are referencing any of the source code in your app module then you will either have to move the sources to the Di module or import the module itself. If you are referencing any external libraries and you are not able to resolve them means that you are missing a library in your imports. In your case, you said that you are not resolving ByteBuffer and JSON classes whichh I think are in libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar. For this to work, you have to import that library into your di module. To do that, put in your di gradle file under dependencies.

Comment: This procedure will create a .jar and import automatically into your project at compile time.

Comment: Ok i have imported in my "di" json and httpcore lib, now i resolve this problem, but now ConnectivityManager, NetworkInfo ecc doesn't work...

Comment: You should move those classes in your Di module as well then.

Comment: Last  question where i can found lastest json jar ?

Comment: Maven repository is always a good choice: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json